# How can I make the whole HTML date field clickable?

Tags: html

I'm using a HTML date field in a registration form, I'm using Laravel 7 to make my application. In my "register" blade view, I have a HTML date field that I would like to open the calendar when the whole date section is clicked. How can I achieve this? For now, the calendar opens when the little calendar icon is clicked. Please help.

In my view:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<label for="start_date">Start Date</label><span class="required">*</span>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date"  name="start_date" value="{{ old('start_date') }}" required>                            
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve the desired functionality like below.

```html
<style>
.form-control input {
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    padding: .75rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<label for="start_date">Start Date</label><span class="required">*</span>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="start_date"  name="start_date" value="{{ old('start_date') }}" required>                            
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it has worked, but the calendar icon has disappeared, I would like it to be at the end of the field.

Comment: you can play around using css, as this html 5 datepicker has limited access for user end to customize.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a challenge with my date field. The whole section is clickable but the problem is that when I move the mouse out of the date field to other fields above it, the cursor appears on the other fields as well and when I click it opens the date. I have tried to remove it with JavaScript `onmouseout` but it didn't work.

Comment: customize width and height according to your needs in "input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator" style attribute , e.g put height to 20px and width to 135px and you can get your desired results

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I have been struggling for hours, tried different widgets, and then decided to do another search. Found your answer. Apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In a React application, you achieve this by doing the following:

```
<input type="date" onClick={(e) => e.currentTarget.showPicker()}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type='date']::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
            opacity: 0;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

It is a bit of a hack but I would try making the default calendar not appear. Then choose your own icon to put in an absolute position. By making the default calendar not visible through opacity but settings its width to the full width of the input you are in turn making the entire field clickable for a date picker. Hope this helps.. You could also keep the opacity as is and just use the default calendar icon but I like to choose my own and I do something like this to position it

```
  svg {
            fill: black;
            width: 20px;
            left: 12px;
            top: 19%;
            position: absolute;
        }
```